# How to set-up spring security without inMemoryAuthentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've my spring security up and running. It's using my own authentication provider since the authentication is done by a host system.

Since I want to have annotation based security I added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` to my servlet configuration.

Unfortunately this was triggering a *AuthenticationManager is required* exception. The only way to avoid this exception was to add a `configureGlobal` method to the servlet config with an `inMemoryAuthentication`.

Obviously I don't want this inMemoryAuthentication since the application depends on my own host authentication. How can I get rid of the inMemoryAuthentication?

This is my servlet configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Import({ 
    FooControllerConfig.class, 
})
public class FooServerletConfig {

    @Autowired
    //@formatter:off
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }
    //@formatter:on

}
```

This is the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class FooSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    //@formatter:off
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(aS400AuthenticationProvider())
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authorized")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("clientId")
                .successHandler(fooAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(fooAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(fooRememberMeServices())
                .key(CookieService.LIR_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
            ;
    }
    //@formatter:on

}
```

This is the exception I get if the `configureGlobal` method is missing:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /FOO threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `auth.inMemoryAuthentication()` you should try `auth.authenticationProvider(new YourAuthenticationProvider())`.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others who is in need of this.

## 1. JDBC Authentication

For implementing jdbcAuthentication you need to write two queries to your database tables
**Query1:** ***usersByUsernameQuery*** (Sets the query to be used for finding a user by their username.)
**Query2:** ***authoritiesByUsernameQuery*** (Sets the query to be used for finding a user's authorities by their username.)

Either it may be java configuration or xml configuration, all you need to do is 
1. Create datasource
2. Configure jdbc authentication in `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` by injecting datasource dependency and configuring usersByUsernameQuery and authoritiesByUsernameQuery.
3. Configure HttpSecurity. Details and defaults given below 
----- Configure intercept-url pattern and authorization for those url's

```
Default role of unauthenticated user = ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

----- Configure form login to avoid default login screen and **default behavior given below**.

```
login-page        = "/login" with HTTP get
usernameParameter = "username"
passwordParameter = "password"
failureUrl        = "/login?error"
loginProcessingUrl= "/login" with HTTP post
successUrl        = "/"
```

----- Configure logout to override default behavior.

```
logoutUrl        = "/logout"
logoutSuccessUrl = "/login?logout"
```

----- Configure session management to override default behavior

```
expiredUrl         = "/login?expired"
invalidate-session = true //you can set false and use delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
maximumSessions    = The default is to allow any number of sessions for a users.
```

#### Javaconfig way

If this is not sufficient download from my github repository. [Working copy of Spring security  with Java configuration](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/springsecurity-autologout/tree/master/javaconfig)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(2);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(5);

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from userdetails where userName=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select ud.username as username, rm.name as role from userdetails ud INNER JOIN rolemaster rm ON rm.id = ud.roleId  where username = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/login", "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/config/*", "/app/admin/*")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/app/user/*")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/user/dashboard")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();

        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

#### XML configuration way

If this is not sufficient download from my github repository. [Working copy of Spring security  with XML configuration](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/springsecurity-autologout/tree/master/xmlconfig)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">  

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/config/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/app/user/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/app/user/dashboard" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
            username-parameter="userName"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <logout invalidate-session="false" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?expired=true">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>

    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" /> 
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username, password, enabled from userdetails where userName=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select ud.username as username, rm.name as role from userdetails ud INNER JOIN rolemaster rm ON rm.id = ud.roleId  where username = ?" />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
    <beans:bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.pvn.mvctiles.configuration.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
         <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc" />
         <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
         <beans:property name="password" value="root"/>
         <beans:property name="initialSize" value="2" />
         <beans:property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </beans:bean>       
</beans:beans>
```

## 2. Implement UserDetailsService in your Dao and inject UserDetailService in Authentication manager buider

Here you need to override loadUserByUsername method
1. load user **password** from database by username passed as arguement in the method.
2. Load **authorities** for user from database and construct a list of GrantedAuthority
3. Create User by passing password and authorities fetched in step 1 and step 2
4. Return UserDetail object so that authentication and authorization will be taken care by spring container itself.

```java
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao, UserDetailsService
{

    Logger          OUT = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory  sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();)
        {

            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<DbUserDetails> userCriteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DbUserDetails.class);
            Root<DbUserDetails> userRoot = userCriteria.from(DbUserDetails.class);
            userCriteria.select(userRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("userName"), username));

            Query<DbUserDetails> userQuery =session.createQuery(userCriteria);
            DbUserDetails dbUser = userQuery.getSingleResult();

            CriteriaQuery<RoleMaster> roleCriteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RoleMaster.class);
            Root<RoleMaster> roleRoot = roleCriteria.from(RoleMaster.class);
            roleCriteria.select(roleRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(roleRoot.get("id"), dbUser.getRoleId()));

            Query<RoleMaster> roleQuery =session.createQuery(roleCriteria);
            RoleMaster role = roleQuery.getSingleResult();

            List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));

            return new User(username, dbUser.getPassword(),true, true, true, true, authList);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OUT.error("Exception - {}", e);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Exception caught", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{   
    @Autowired
    UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;

    @Autowired
    public void configureUserDetailsService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDaoImpl);
    }
    ...
}
```

## 3. By registering custom Authentication Provider.

In previous step(implementing UserDetailsService) loadUserByUsername method was passed only with username arguement (no way of getting password), but while authenticating with third party system, it will not provide you the stored credentials but instead it will ask you to provide credentials. Hence you need both username and password. You can get it by implementing AuthenticationProvider as given below. Once authentication is success against third party system you just need to set and return a token(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) to the spring security.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    ...
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider 
{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        //Do your authentication
        // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        if (authenticatedSuccessfully) 
        {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } 
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) 
    {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```